# How can I pass a non-static member function to ftw?

Tags: c++, non-static

I'm new in C++ coding and I'm having this problem:
I would like to do something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <ftw.h>

class Foo {
public: 
    int func1 (const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb, int typeflag){
        total += sb->st_size;
        std::cout << total << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    
    int func2(){
        ftw("plots", func1, 3);
    }
    
    int total;
};
```

Is there any work around the fact that func1 is not static? I also tried to define a lambda (or a std::function) inside `func2()` in order to pass it to ftw(), but it needs `int (*)(const char*, const stat*, int)` as second parameter, hence it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What’s the broader context? I don’t know anything about `ftw`.

Comment: @Ben https://linux.die.net/man/3/ftw

Comment: In C++17 you can use `<filesystem>`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator if you are stuck using C, you can’t pass member-functions or lambdas.

Answer (score 3):

You could store the `std::function` in a static variable, and have a static function that "forwards" the call:

```
class Foo {
public: 
    int func1 (const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb, int typeflag){
        total += sb->st_size;
        std::cout << total << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    
    int func2(){
        ftwForwardTo = [&this] (const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb, int typeflag) {
            return func1(fpath, sb, typeflag);
        };
        ftw("plots", forwardFtw, 3);
    }
    
    int total;

private:
    static std::function<int(const char *, const stat *, int)> ftwForwardTo;

    static int forwardFtw(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb, int typeflag){
        ftwForwardFunc(fpath, sb, typeflag);
    }
};
```

I didn't test this code but you get the idea.

Note that this is neither thread-safe nor reentrant.

---

In C++17, you can use [`std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) for a less hacky solution.

For older C++ versions, you can probably find something in Boost.

Answer (score 2):

`func1` has hidden parameter called `this`, this means its signature does not match the requirements of ftw parameter.

I would encourage you to make static/global function and prepare some global or singletone variable to hold the target function `func1`